# MDX: Advice on Advancing a query

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx

I have an MDX statement that works, but I'd like to expand it.  The current statement brings back the top 10 for a specific year where the rows are the states, and the column the total earnings.  I would like to produce 5 columns -- each column and row set representing a different year. How would I go about achieving this?

```
  with
  member measures.[Total Earnings] as 
  (measures.[Total GS]) + (measures.[Total DE]) + (measures.[Total SE])
    set [Top 10 States] as
    topcount 
  (
    {Stores.[State Code]. [State Code].members},
     10,
     (Measures.[Total Earnings], [Time].[C Year].[2011])
  )
  select
   {([Measures].[Total  Earnings])} on columns,
     {[Top 10 States]} on rows
    from LoyaltyMeasurements
     Where (Time.[C Year].[2011]);
```

Comment: More detail needed: do you still want the top 10 states for the selected year and the [total earnings] for those 10 for the 5 previous years, or do you want 10 columns where the first two have the top 10 states for 2011 with values, then next 2 have the top 10 states for 2010 with values, etc... ??

Comment: I'm looking for the top 10 states for the selected year and 4 years prior. So the columns might look like Total Earnings - 2011, Total Earnings - 2010, etc. while there would still be 10 rows listing the state codes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you are looking for is ParallelPeriod

```
MEMBER measures.[Total Earnings Prev1] as 
    Aggregate(
    ParallelPeriod([Time].[C Year], 1, [Time].CurrentMember),
    (measures.[Total GS]) + (measures.[Total DE]) + (measures.[Total SE])
    )
```